# Argument error while installing virtualenvwrapper-powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

Trying to install virtualenvwrapper-powershell but having following error:

```
chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'
```

I got it after reading this article:

> https://bitbucket.org/guillermooo/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/issues/5/cant-install-package-with-python3-and-pip

(actually i had a problem described in it)
Guy named Alexander Zonov suggested:

> We have solution already. Download virtualenvwrapper-powershell Find
>   file setup.py Change problem string to this one TOKEN_READ =
>   0x00020000 | 0x0008 Use "python setup.py install" command to install
>   virtualenvwrapper-powershell

And after i've done i got my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8\distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "C:\Python35\virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8\distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\Python35\virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8\distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download

    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "C:\Python35\virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8\distribute_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
    _extractall(tar)
  File "C:\Python35\virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8\distribute_setup.py", line 459, in _extractall
    self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'
```

Any hints how may I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Goto line no: 459 in "distribute_setup.py" and try adding an empty argument, like this: chown(tarinfo, dirpath, '');

worked for me.

I'm sure this isn't a perfect solution, but it's kinda like quickfix. helped me though.

Comment: Worked for me. in ex_setup.py, change from 'self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)' to 'self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath, '')' worked. Love ya.