# Python package (Newspaper) install error

Tags: python, python-newspaper

Trying to install a package which failed with the error below. I googled and installed setuptools - still getting same error.

Command: `pip install newspaper`

```
Collecting nltk==2.0.5 (from newspaper)
  Using cached nltk-2.0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz
    Extracting in C:\Users\pratik\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0mun48pu
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\pratik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
        raise ImportError
    ImportError

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\pratik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "c:\users\pratik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "c:\users\pratik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
        _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
      File "c:\users\pratik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\distribute_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
        _extractall(tar)
      File "c:\users\pratik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk\distribute_setup.py", line 467, in _extractall
        self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
    TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\pratik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6gyje7fp\nltk
```

Comment: Please, check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/32922903/580709 . In your case it is line #467

Comment: I realized I was installing wrong version of package due to misleading and contradictory information on package page. Correct package name for Python 3 - pip3 install newspaper3k

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to install using python3 then run 
`pip3 install newspaper3k`

if you're trying to install for python2 and want newspaper first run

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

then

`pip install newspaper`